# Is it good practice to have many user controls for different purposes

Tags: c#, sharepoint, user-controls, webforms

I have a gridview and I am doing a lot of operations on it, now I was wondering if I should add user controls or keep adding code to it.

gridview is in a user control itself.

Comment: If you will reuse them elsewhere, sure. However, make sure you follow the YAGNI Principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit or performance issue in case of use of as many user controls as you want.

Ofcourse, implementation of business logic on the user controls can effect the performance.

Performance for usercontrols also depends upon postbacks you are handling with them.

This can be mitigated by two things:

1. Make sure user controls cache all their data on first load and never re-load it unless     explicitly instructed to (usually by an event from a lower-level service)
2. Ensure the controls all use a set of common services which can reuse data. E.g. if two controls need access to the customers list, and they are executing in the context of the same request session, that should only require one customer list lookup.